# example; $H^t(K)=\infty$, and $H^s(K)=0$ for all $s > t$

Tags: hausdorff-measure

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and $H^s$ be the $s$-dimentional Hausdorff measure.

Does there exist $0<t<n$, and $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$; compact set

such that $H^t(K)=\infty$, and

$H^s(K)=0$ for all $s > t$?

Comment: Yes --- Use a (generalized) Cantor set with nonzero finite measure for a Hausdorff measure function that approaches zero quicker than $x^t$ and slower than any power of $x$ greater than $t,$ such as $-\frac{x^t}{\log x} = \frac{x^t}{\log (1/x)}.$ More precise examples than this were actually given by Hausdorff in his 1918 paper where Hausdorff measure was introduced. The bibliography of [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2007-135-10/S0002-9939-07-09019-3/S0002-9939-07-09019-3.pdf) might be useful.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check on it.